# Waiting for block to finish to reload UITableView Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, objective-c-blocks

I currently have a problem regarding blocks, the application it self is loading reports in from an XML document. The parser works however I have a problem when loading it into the mainArray and reloading the data after the block has finished. I have tried using semaphores to set the event off when the process is finished. However because the XML is not very fast at loading, the mainArray is populated and the UITableView's data is reloaded. I am currently using this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, kNilOptions), ^{

    XmlParser *xml = [[XmlParser alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStaticURL];
    [xml loadXML:url];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        mainArray = [xml parsedArray];
        [UiTableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

This will then populate the array correctly and load in what I want from the objects. 
How would I get this code :

```
  mainArray = [xml parsedArray];
  [UiTableView reloadData];
```

to Execute after

```
    XmlParser *xml = [[XmlParser alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStaticURL];
    [xml loadXML:url];
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using TBXML to parse the XML feed into the [xml parsedArray];       Specifically TBXML+HTTP.h&.m files to grab the data.

Comment: Try with the XmlParser delegate methods.

Comment: I forgotten to mention that I am using TBXML to load in the XML feed.

Comment: Does `XmlParser` work in a async way ?

Comment: When this call [xml loadXML:url]; is made it is sent to run in this : 

parser = [TBXML newTBXMLWithURL:newURL success:^(TBXML *tbxml ) { //dosomething} failure:^(TBXML *tbxml, NSError *error) {       NSLog(@"Error");
}];

So best Guess is yes i think so.

Comment: You should call `mainArray = [xml parsedArray];
  [UiTableView reloadData];` in `success:^(){}` block. BTW you should @KudoCC or I don't get noticed.

Comment: @KudoCC Ok Thanks for that. I'll have a go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to change dispatch_after to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
which should not execute until the xml parsing has finished.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    XmlParser *xml = [[XmlParser alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStaticURL];
    [xml loadXML:url];

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        mainArray = [xml parsedArray];
        [UiTableView reloadData];

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be as below :-

1. create a thread to perform a method as below in viewDidload or anyplace u want.

   ```
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(readXML) toTarget:self withObject:nil];    //this way ur main thread won't be blocked and reading of xml will be done in background thread.
   ```

Then,

```
  -(void)readXML
  {
    XmlParser *xml = [[XmlParser alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStaticURL];
    [xml loadXML:url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableWithXML) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];      //to update on main thread.
  } 

  -(void)reloadTableWithXML
  {
    mainArray = [xml parsedArray];
    [UiTableView reloadData];
  }
```

hope helpful to u !